# recursive function running out of memory faster with malloc

Tags: c

I have the following codes:

```
int main (void)
{
  k++;
  if (k % 10000 == 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "%d ", k / 10000);
  main ();
  return 0;
}
```

```
int main (void)
{
  int *tmp;    
  tmp = malloc (100 * sizeof (int));    
  k++;
  if (k % 10000 == 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "%d ", k / 10000);
  main ();
  return 0;
}
```

`k` is a global variable, its initial value is 0. The program calls itself recursively until the codes fills up the stack. Both programs provoke a segmentation fault.

In the second one the stack overflow happens much sooner. However, since the `malloc` function only returns a pointer the stack shouldn't be noticing the difference. Is the segmentation fault happening sooner because the heap, where the dynamic memory is allocated, is smaller than the stack?

*edit: The programs crashing is not the issue, that's the point of those two programs. I just want to know why the second code gets a segmentation fault earlier than the first, and if I'm wrong in the explanation I provide.
Compiled with gcc (gcc *code* -o *output*)

Comment: There is no `rec2` defined.

Comment: The second version uses more stack space per invocation than the first:  Space is used for `tmp`.  It may also use more space to spill registers before calling `rec2`.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], including definitions of `k` and `rec2`. Your question should include **all** the code needed to run your programs and should show the output of both programs (or at least a portion of the final output of each).

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? What code did your compiler generate?

Comment: @EricPostpischil this is correct observation, I was confused.

Comment: My apologies, the code has been corrected, it says "main" where "rec2" was before.

Comment: You have edited the code to fix the `rec2` problem. Unfortunately, you have still not provided complete information. What is the definition of `k`? What is the output of the first program? (What is the last number it prints before aborting?) What is the output of the second program. Additionally, which compiler are you using? What switches are you using to compile? If you compile it to assembly, instead of to an object file, or provide us sufficient information to, we can examine the assembly and confirm how much stack space is being used. **Provide the information requested.**

Comment: Additionally, note that `main` should be declared as either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. `void main()` is not proper, except that C implementations may allow non-standard declarations.

Comment: If you enable optimizations a compiler can recognize that `main` is properly tail-recursive and resort to TCO and that allocated memory is not required and it will *not* crash. I.e. there is nothing to ask. See for example [this one](https://godbolt.org/z/kN_YWc) with Clang - no `malloc`, no `call main`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the call to `rec2()` is changed to `main()` so that it is recursive in the same manner as the first example, then the second example includes a local variable (int * tmp), that the first example doesn't. That alone will take 4 or 8 bytes (32 bit or 64 bit build) of stack space for each call. You can change the code to int * volatile tmp = (int *)0; , and it should still fail in the same manner. In most environments, the heap and the stack handled separately, and normally there is much more heap space than stack space.

update - using Visual Studio on the following code, with a 32 bit release build, the last display before stack overflow is 1285, with the #if 0 changed to #if 1, the last display is 642. With a 64 bit build, the last display is 212 in either case (with #if 0 or #if 1), because one of the registers that is stored in caller allocated stack (32 bytes for rcx, rdx, r8, r9) is apparently used for tmp.

```
static int k;

int main()
{
#if 0     /* change to #if 1 to use tmp */
int * volatile tmp = (int *)0;
#endif
    k++;
    if (k % 100 == 0)
        fprintf (stderr, "%d ", k / 100);
    main();
}
```

Comment: `tmp` should not take any stack space because it is not used, not even passed to `rec2`, so optimization should remove it. Even if the program is compiled without optimization, no recursion to `main` is shown in the second program, so the stack space for `tmp` is a single instance, which will have minimal effect on when the program terminates. We cannot properly discern what happens in this program without seeing the definition of `rec2`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - missed an edit. Answer was updated to note the assumption that `rec2()` is changed to `main()`, so that it is consistent with first example.

Comment: Still, `tmp` is not the best candidate, but the call to `malloc` itself.

Comment: @EugeneSh - depending on the compiler, probably just declaring `int * volatile tmp = 0;` would be enough to keep a compiler from optimizing out tmp